# Unit test XPath Constraint

Tags: java, xpath, orbeon, xforms

In our forms we use an XPath constraint validation like:

```
final String constraint =
  "("                   + 
  constraint            + 
  ") and not(contains(" +
  fileNameElt           + 
  ",'&'))"              ;
```

Is there a way to unit test this constraint. This will be useful if we have some more advanced constraints.

For example compare a string with the set constraint.

Comment: What XForms processor you are  using?

Comment: We are using the xForm processor Orbeon

Comment: We think that it is not possible to JUnit test it without starting Orbeon.

Comment: @Jeroen And by "unit test", you mean "run the XPath" when your unit tests are running? Also, where is that code at runtime? Is it Java code at runtime? Is it running inside Orbeon Forms somehow? If so, how? Are you adding your own classes or jar to the Orbeon Forms web app?